# Leaflet: Load GeoJSON point data in polygon, when selecting polygon

Tags: leaflet, large-datasets

I've got a point dataset (~ 160.000 points) which has a filesize of around 30 MB. Because that is too large I decided to slit it into 12 separate GeoJSON files. I've got a map with 12 polygons. When the user will select one polygon I want the related GeoJSON point file to be downloaded and displayed on the map. Therefore I am loading the point data script dynamically:

```js
    function onclick(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds()); // Zoom to Polygon
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script= document.createElement('script');
        script.type= 'text/javascript';
        var data = feature.properties.name; // getting the name of the selected polygon, point data is namend by polygon
        var datafile = '.js';
        script.src= data + datafile;
        head.appendChild(script);
        pointToLayer: marker_icon;
        map.addLayer(data);
    };
```

As I found out with the inspector of my webbrowser, the point data file will be loaded successfully, but the points are not getting into the map. The datafile looks like that:

```js
var data = {type:"FeatureCollection", features: [
{ type: "Feature", properties: { LN: "412C-6351", AH: 33.94, BA: "1958\/03\/01", BE: "1899\/12\/31", BV: "UN"  }, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 13.46311, 52.46391 ] } }]};
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is line `pointToLayer: marker_icon;` supposed to do? It looks like invalid syntax.

Comment: It's calling this function:

function marker_icon(feature, latlng) {
 return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
   radius: 8.0,
   fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.ET),
   color: getColor(feature.properties.ET),
   weight: 1,
   opacity: 1.0,
   fillOpacity: 0.75
  })
 }

Comment: I admit I'm not familiar with this syntax. Where does it come from? And how are then and from where parameters `feature` and `latlng` passed to the function call?